# How to make TextBox Visibility with Combobox SelectedValue?

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to change TextBox Visability by ComboboxItems. For example, I have ComboBox with two items: "visible" and "hidden". If ComboBox selectedValue is "visible" - TextBox Visability value is "visible" and if ComboBox selectedValue is "hidden" - TextBox Visability value is "hidden" too.
I need to decide this problem only with XAML, not use back code or VM. For example  or the other. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a style trigger for that.

```
<ComboBox Name="myCombo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" SelectedIndex="0" SelectedValuePath="Content">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="117.714285714286"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Hidden" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="117.714285714286"/>
</ComboBox>
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,37,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=myCombo, Path=SelectedValue}" Value="Hidden">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Why not just bind `<TextBox Visibility="{Binding ElementName=myCombo, Path=SelectedValue}" .../>`?

Comment: That actually works. I thought a converter might have been needed to convert from string to visibility.

Comment: Nope, there’s automatic value conversion. The Value in the Setter is just a String too.